# Why the output image will be rotated?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I build a watermark creator by OpenCV. The program could create watermark in the 4 corner of a source image. I haven't change the source image direction and the output image is also copied from the merge of source image and watermark. When I make a test, a image was rotated and the watermark was in the incorrect place. However when I use the thumbnail of that image for test, the direction is correct. So I guess the problem is in the size of image.

Here is my code.

```
#include "test.h"

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define LEFT_TOP 0
#define LEFT_DOWN 1
#define MIDDLE 2
#define RIGHT_TOP 3
#define rIGHT_DOWN 4

//watermark position offset
#define off_ratio 40

//the ratio of watermark and the source image 

#define length_ratio 6

int main_test(int argc , char * argv[])
{

    //Read from alpha channel ，Transparent

    Mat img_src = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    cout << (int)img_src.at<Vec4b>(0,0)[0] << endl
    << (int)img_src.at<Vec4b>(0,0)[1] << endl
    << (int)img_src.at<Vec4b>(0,0)[2] << endl
    << (int)img_src.at<Vec4b>(0,0)[3] << endl;

    cout << (int)img_src.at<Vec4b>(10,10)[0] << endl
    << (int)img_src.at<Vec4b>(10,10)[1] << endl
    << (int)img_src.at<Vec4b>(10,10)[2] << endl
    << (int)img_src.at<Vec4b>(10,10)[3] << endl;
    return 0;
}



int add_watermask(Mat & img_roi, Mat img_water_mask, float scale_ratio)
{

    vector<Mat>src_channels;
    vector<Mat>watermark_channels;

    //Split the channel
    split(img_roi, src_channels);
    split(img_water_mask, watermark_channels);

    if (scale_ratio < 1)
    {
        watermark_channels[3] *= scale_ratio;
        scale_ratio = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //dstt_channels[i] = dstt_channels[i].mul(255.0 / scale - scr_channels[3], scale / 255.0);
        //dstt_channels[i] += scr_channels[i].mul(scr_channels[3], scale / 255.0);
        src_channels[i] = src_channels[i].mul(255.0 / scale_ratio - watermark_channels[3], scale_ratio / 255.0);
        src_channels[i] += watermark_channels[i].mul(watermark_channels[3], scale_ratio / 255.0);
    }

    merge(src_channels, img_roi);
    return 0;
}


//Calculate the watermark position in the source image
int process_pose(Mat & src, Mat & water, Mat & roi, Mat & water_resize, int pose)
{

    int width_src = src.cols;
    int height_src = src.rows;

    int width_water = water.cols;
    int height_water = water.rows;

    int max_length_src = max(width_src, height_src);

    //5% offset of the image length
    int off = max_length_src / off_ratio;

    //Watermark length is 1/6 of the source image
    int length_1_6 = max_length_src / length_ratio;

    int scale_width_water = length_1_6;
    int scale_height_water = length_1_6 * height_water / width_water;


    //if the source image width larger than height，then keep the scale of watermark's height and source image' height
    if(width_src > height_src) {
        if ((off * 2 + scale_height_water) > height_src) {
            off = height_src / off_ratio;
            scale_height_water = height_src / length_ratio;
            scale_width_water = scale_height_water * width_water / height_water;
        }
    }
        //if the source image height larger than width，then keep the scale of watermark's width and source image' width
    else{
        if((off * 2 + scale_width_water) > width_src)
        {
            off = width_src / off_ratio;
            scale_width_water = width_src / length_ratio;
            scale_height_water = scale_width_water * height_water / width_water;
        }
    }

    int ret = 0 ;

    Rect pose_water = {0,0,0,0};

    pose_water.width = scale_width_water;
    pose_water.height = scale_height_water;


    switch(pose)
    {
        case 0:
            pose_water.x = off;
            pose_water.y = off;
            break;

        case 1:
            pose_water.x = off;
            pose_water.y = height_src - off - scale_height_water;
            break;

        case 2:
            pose_water.x = (width_src - scale_width_water)/2;
            pose_water.y = (height_src - scale_height_water)/2;
            break;

        case 3:
            pose_water.x = width_src - scale_width_water - off;
            pose_water.y = off;
            break;

        case 4:
            pose_water.x = width_src - scale_width_water - off;
            pose_water.y = height_src - scale_height_water - off;
            break;
        default:
            printf("wrong pose \n");
            ret = -1;
            break;

    }

    if(ret == -1)
    {
        return  ret;
    }

    roi = src(pose_water);

    resize(water, water_resize, Size(scale_width_water, scale_height_water));
    return  0;
}


int main(int argc , char * argv[])
{


    if(argc < 6)
    {
        cout << "used error\n";
        cout <<"used follow: " << argv[0] << " img1(jpg) img2(png) Tranparacy(0-100) Position（LEFT_TOP（0）， LEFT_DOWN（1）， MIDDLE（2）， RIGHT_TOP（3），RIGHT_DOWN（4））， the result\n";
        cout << "example: /home/disk/0_raw.jpg /home/disk/logo.png 0 0 /home/disk/logo_0_test.jpg \n";
        return 103;
    }
    Mat img_src = imread(argv[1]);
    Mat img_water_mark = imread(argv[2], -1);

    //Check the argument
    if(img_src.data == NULL || img_water_mark.data == NULL)
    {
        cout << "read img failed check it\n"
        << "img1: " << argv[1] << endl
        << "img1: " << argv[1] << endl;

        return 101;
    }

    //Grey convert to color
    if(img_src.channels() != 3)
    {
        cvtColor(img_src, img_src, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    }
    //Check the channel is correct

    if(img_src.channels() != 3 || img_water_mark.channels() != 4)
    {
        cout << "img 's channnel is error ,check it \n";
        return 102;
    }

    //Default watermark width is larger than height

    if(img_water_mark.cols < img_water_mark.rows)
    {
        cout << "Watermark height large than width， check it \n";
        return 104;
    }

    //Transparency(0-100)

    int scale = atoi(argv[3]);
    float scale_ratio = (1- scale / 100.0);

    if (scale_ratio > 1.0 || scale_ratio < 0.0)
    {
        cout << "scale is error , put scale in 1~100\n";

        return 105;
    }


    int pose = atoi(argv[4]);

    Mat src_copy  = img_src.clone();
    Mat water_copy = img_water_mark.clone();

    Mat roi, water_resize ;

    int ret = process_pose(src_copy, water_copy, roi, water_resize, pose);

    if(ret == -1)
    {
        printf("other pose not in LEFT_TOP（0）， LEFT_DOWN（1）， MIDDLE（2）， RIGHT_TOP（3），RIGHT_DOWN（4）， check it\n");
        return 106;
    }

//    Mat img_roi(img_src, cvRect(0, 0, img_water_mark.cols, img_water_mark.rows));
//    add_watermask(img_roi, img_water_mark, scale_ratio);

    add_watermask(roi, water_resize, scale_ratio);

    //imshow("img", src_copy);
    imwrite(argv[5], src_copy);
    //waitKey();
    return  0;

}
```

I want to create a watermark in the RIGHT_DOWN position of the image, but the output image was rotated. So the watermark position is wrong.

Due to the limit of stackoverflow I can only upload a image less than 2MB. The original source image is 6MB. Here is the thumbnail of the source image.
[image]

Here is the thumbnail of the original source image output.
[image]

Caution: When I use the thumbnail of original image as input, the result is correct.

Here is the output when I use thumbnail of source image as input.[image]

Comment: Cameras often put a rotation notation in the EXIF of an image file. Some programs read that rotation in order to display it properly, and some ignore it. A program which outputs a new image can either copy that rotation flag or lose it. In this case it looks like OpenCV does not automatically rotate the image for you nor does it copy the rotation flag to the output.

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems you are right. The orientation of the source image is 270 degree. OpenCV automatically read the orientation. The next problem puzzle me is how to prevent OpenCV read the orientation information. Do you have good ideal? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

As @MarkRansom says, some cameras store an EXIF *"Orientation"* field in the headers of images.

You have a few options, using **exiftool**, **jhead** or **ImageMagick** all of which are installed on many Linux distros and are available for macOS and Windows.

So, to see the field with **exiftool**:

```
exiftool -Orientation image.jpg
   Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
```

Or with **jhead**:

```
jhead -v image.jpg | grep -i orien
Orientation = 1
```

Or with **ImageMagick**:

```
identify -verbose image.jpg | grep -i orient
   Orientation: TopLeft
   exif:Orientation: 1
```

So, you could do that, and correct for it with OpenCV using a `rotate()`. Or you could correct it with **ImageMagick** outside of **OpenCV**:

```
mogrify -auto-orient image.jpg             # correct orientation of single image
convert image.jpg -auto-orient result.jpg  # alternative, more verbose but same as above  
mogrify -auto-orient *.jpg                 # correct orientation of all images
```

Beware that **mogrify** will change all your images irreversibly, so be sure that you make a backup before testing.

---

Note that **jhead** is probably the easiest to install, lightest weight option of the three in Windows. In Linux or macOS, **exiftool** is the lightest weight as it is just a Perl script. **ImageMagick** is vastly more powerful, and heavier weight and somewhat harder to install - IMHO.

---

**Useful links**

[Tutorial](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif#cite_note-21)

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I check the orientation of the image, it is 270 degree. However do you have any good ideal to prevent OpenCV automatically read the orientation information? Since I can't delete all the exif info, I need to use some tricks to keep the image direction.

Comment: You can delete (i.e. strip) all the EXIF information if you want to `mogrify -strip *.jpg`

Comment: I need to keep the EXIF info and I use OpenCV 2.4.10. OpenCV 2.4.X can't use the CV_LOAD_IMAGE_IGNORE_ORIENTATION flag while OpenCV can't read exif info. I'm going to collapse

Comment: You can change just the orientation field with `exiftool -Orientation=1 -n image.jpg` Or with **ImageMagick**, `mogrify -orient top-left image.jpg`