# Why is dlib's load_rgb_image() method rotating some of my images?

Tags: python, image, opencv, dlib

I'm working on image processing with some images I collected myself. Dlib's `dlib.load_rgb_image('image_path')` method swaps the rows and columns on **some** images while OpenCV's `cv2.imread('image_path')` method does not.

I don't want to go in and rotate some of these offending images myself manually because I'm creating an app.

Check out the results below

```
img = dlib.load_rgb_image("myimg.jpg")
print(img.shape)

--------------------
OUTPUT: (1944, 2592, 3)
(the resultant image is rotated 90 degrees clockwise)
```

while OpenCV's method returns the correct shape:

```
img = cv2.imread("myimg.jpg")
print(img.shape)

--------------------
OUTPUT: (2592, 1944, 3)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I am also attaching the image details of one of the offending photos:

[image: image.png]

Comment: it is on the dlib document that `dlib.load_rgb_image(filename: unicode) → numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),uint8]`. It's just different in the order of width and height

Comment: Yeah, I did check out the docs. This doesn't make sense the in a numpy array of an image the _rows=height_of_image_, and _cols=width_of_image_.

Comment: you can use `np.transpose` to get cv2 format

Comment: Plus, as stated above the problem of rotated image occurs in **some** of the images, **not all**

Comment: I was planning to use Dlib all the way, due to some portability constraints. But again how to know which images to transpose and which to not transpose.

Comment: I see. I think if it happened only in some images, it could be an issue. You better inform this problem in the dlib github

Comment: Some images have `Orientation` set in their EXIF data - particularly camera phone ones. OpenCV ignores it. You can check with `exiftool` or ImageMagick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146220/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Mark Setchell, for pointing me in the right direction.

The EXIF data is the key, here.

`dlib.load_rgb_image()` does not take into account the EXIF `orientation` metadata, so some images are read incorrectly. To remedy this EXIF orientation tag of an image needs to be checked to perform the correct rotation on it.

Here are a few good answers:
[Rotating an image with orientation specified in EXIF using Python without PIL including the thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872331/rotating-an-image-with-orientation-specified-in-exif-using-python-without-pil-in)

Apparently, since OpenCV 3.1 `imread` handles EXIF orientation perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for working it out and sharing back with the Stack Overflow community. You can accept your own answer and bag the points, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, will do that. Apparently, can't accept my own answer for at least two days. LOL