# resize function rotates image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I use python opencv

```
    dim = (width, height)
    resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

The problem is that it resizes and rotates the image. How can I fix it? I need only resize it.

Comment: Please provide an example image.

Comment: You are probably suffering from the *"orientation"* information encoded in the header... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146220/2836621