# Shapes of a same portrait image are different when using imread and imdecode of OpenCV

Tags: python, flask, opencv

I'm making an API of creating thumbnail of an image using Python.(Flask, OpenCV)

With a same portrait image,(width:height=3:4=3024:4032)

`img = cv2.imread('portrait.jpg')`

The shape of `img` is (4032, 3024, 3).

```
img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(request.files['file'].read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

The shape of `img` is (3024, 4032, 3).

For that reason, my cropping logic doesn't work as I intend when it is a portrait.

Do I miss something? or Should I pass additional orientation parameter to rotate the image?

Regards, Lee

Comment: use the same parameter. What's the result with: `img = cv2.imread('portrait.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`?

Comment: I guess it may be related to the EXIF `Orientation` metadata... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146220/2836621

Comment: @Miki Thank you very much, With `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` param, the shapes are same!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for your comment about `Exif Orientation`. My problem is solved by changing `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` param to `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` in `imdecode` to consider Exif orientation.