# avoid image rotation with open cv imread

Tags: opencv, imread

I am trying to load an image with cv2.imread().

It works fine when width>height. However, when height>width, the output is sometimes rotated.

Is there a way to avoid this rotation?

Thank you

Comment: Try adding `cv.IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION` to your flags for the `imread()`

Comment: is this also possible to do on mpimg.imread()?

Comment: I presume you are referring to `matplotlib`. If so, sorry I don't know, I wouldn't use that for image I/O.

Comment: There are some useful notes about *"EXIF Orientation"* here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146220/2836621

Comment: the thing is that matplotlib allows me to get the mouseclick inside the image with canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', mouse_click)

Comment: @MarkSetchell anyways, I am not being able to solve it with cv2.imread() and cv2.IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION... Is it possible that it is because the images are jpeg?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224324/discussion-between-bernardo-cortez-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: I can't do chat. Note that there is nothing stopping you opening an image with **OpenCV** and then processing/displaying it with **Matplotlib**, as long as you change the ordering from BGR to RGB. Note also that you can capture mouse clicks with **OpenCV**.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It turns out that the problem was in fact the extension of the photos. Once everything was png, it worked fine